# Translation of "It is found to be"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> The echelon form of the matrix is found to be given by...
>
> La forme échelonnée de la matrice se trouve être donnée par...

I have a feeling that the French turn would sound a bit weird to native speakers. Can we use it?

Comment: Ça me semble correct, même si je préfère de beaucoup le plus simple *est donnée par ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this case the pronominal form of "trouver" in the active voice would be found slightly awkward (but not incorrect in my opinion) and it'd be found preferable to get rid of the verb "trouver".

- La forme  échelonnée de la matrice est donnée par…

Comment: After reading user [Damien](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40466/translation-of-it-is-found-to-be/40467#comment81424_40466)'s comment I realised that the verb "trouver" has no place in the translation; as I wrote it it would have this meaning : « 3. Se trouver avoir/être. Avoir, être par un concours fortuit de circonstances. Il se trouve être un ami de; je me trouve avoir mille francs sur moi. ». Ce n'est pas ce que l'original anglais signifie. I' ll change that now. Sorry for that.